# how can i know what security firebase rule give me a error?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security

I have this firebase security rule:

```
".validate": "newData.val().length < 2"
```

When the new data.length is > 2, Firebase returns a error that says "PERMISSON_DENIED".

I would like to know if there is a way to get a error info like this "the new data is to long".

Thanks

Comment: One can consider the danger of being too informative in security settings. Revealing exactly which rule fails and how, could possibly allow to extract information which is designed to be unavailable. This may be an overshoot of paranoia for a Firebase DB but still needs consideration.

Answer (score 6):

Firebase security rules return the same error, no matter what part failed. You have no control over the error message. If you're troubleshooting why an operation is failing, you can use the Simulator in your Firebase dashboard. But that doesn't seem what you're looking for.

Showing a more intelligent error message to the user is a great idea though. But I'd recommend doing that by validating the data *before* you send it to Firebase. So perform client-side validation and only send the data to Firebase if it passes the validation.

Better yet: don't allow the user to enter more than 2 characters.

Comment: Thanks for confirm! I guess that these was the reason!